# Click Event to Right Click Event Data Binding Template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datatemplate

I am Working with WPF MVVM

I made the following `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type r:CustomControl}">
        <Border x:Name="bord" BorderThickness="0" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="0"
                BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Background}" 
                Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type con:Control}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=TileColorPair[0]}"
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource CMenu}">
            <Button Width="{Binding Size}" Height="{Binding Size}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image x:Name="img"  Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Text}" FontFamily="{DynamicResource DefaultFont}" FontSize="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.CaptionFontSizeKey}}"
                                   Foreground="White"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Border>
```

And I associated a `ContextMenu` on the `Border`.
Each menu has an specific `Command`.

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="CMenu">
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Header="Update">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Width="45" Height="45" Source="/Assembly;component/Resources/edit.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" Header="Select">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Width="45" Height="45"  Source="/Assembly;component/Resources/search.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
```

How do I Bind the Event from the Right Click that activates the `ContextMenu` to the Left Click as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new left button handler on the `Border` element:

```
<Border x:Name="Win"
        Width="40"
        Height="40"
        Background="Purple"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonUp">
```

and then add this:

```
private void UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    var mouseDownEvent =
        new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice,
            Environment.TickCount,
            MouseButton.Right)
        {
            RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseUpEvent,
            Source = Win,
        };


    InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(mouseDownEvent);
}
```

What it does, it basically maps the left-click into right-click.

Comment: What is `Source = Win`  @Chris?

Comment: @Darknesstiller; it's a name of the `Border` element. In my case, `Win`. You can set it `Source = sender`