# kinect griprelease click simulation through xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect, mouseclick-event

I have to capture with a V.1 MS Kinect the hand gestures in order to navigate a web app that has already been created. But I got stuck in the click simulation. 
I created a fullscreen window that covers the whole screen.

```
    <Window x:Class="GettingStarted.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2013"
    Title="MainWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowState="Maximized" Background="{x:Null}">
<Grid>
    <k:KinectSensorChooserUI HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="sensorChooserUi" />
    <k:KinectUserViewer VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" k:KinectRegion.KinectRegion="{Binding ElementName=kinectRegion}" Height="100" UserColoringMode="Manual" />
    <k:KinectRegion Name="kinectRegion">
        <Grid>
            <k:KinectScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HoverBackground="Transparent">
                <StackPanel Height="768" Width="1366" Opacity="0.01" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
                </StackPanel>
            </k:KinectScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </k:KinectRegion>
   </Grid>
```

then there is the c# code:

```
    namespace GettingStarted
    {

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private KinectSensorChooser sensorChooser;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        KinectRegion.AddHandPointerMoveHandler(kinectRegion, OnHandleHandMove);
        KinectRegion.AddHandPointerGripReleaseHandler(kinectRegion, GripReleased);
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        this.sensorChooser = new KinectSensorChooser();
        this.sensorChooser.KinectChanged += SensorChooserOnKinectChanged;
        this.sensorChooserUi.KinectSensorChooser = this.sensorChooser;
        this.sensorChooser.Start();
    }

    private void SensorChooserOnKinectChanged(object sender, KinectChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        bool error = false;
        if (args.OldSensor != null)
        {
            try
            {
                args.OldSensor.DepthStream.Range = DepthRange.Default;
                args.OldSensor.SkeletonStream.EnableTrackingInNearRange = false;
                args.OldSensor.DepthStream.Disable();
                args.OldSensor.SkeletonStream.Disable();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                // KinectSensor might enter an invalid state while enabling/disabling streams or stream features.
                // E.g.: sensor might be abruptly unplugged.
                error = true;
            }
        }

        if (args.NewSensor != null)
        {
            try
            {
                args.NewSensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
                args.NewSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();

                try
                {
                    //args.NewSensor.DepthStream.Range = DepthRange.Near;
                    //args.NewSensor.SkeletonStream.EnableTrackingInNearRange = true;
                    //args.NewSensor.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // Non Kinect for Windows devices do not support Near mode, so reset back to default mode.
                    args.NewSensor.DepthStream.Range = DepthRange.Default;
                    args.NewSensor.SkeletonStream.EnableTrackingInNearRange = false;
                    error = true;
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                error = true;
                // KinectSensor might enter an invalid state while enabling/disabling streams or stream features.
                // E.g.: sensor might be abruptly unplugged.
            }
        }

        if (!error)
            kinectRegion.KinectSensor = args.NewSensor;
    }

    private void OnHandleHandMove(object source, HandPointerEventArgs args)
    {
        // The meat of the hand handle method.
        HandPointer ptr = args.HandPointer;
        Point newPoint = kinectRegion.PointToScreen(ptr.GetPosition(kinectRegion));
        MouseController.MoveMouse(newPoint);
    }

    // HERE'S THE PROBLEM!
    private void GripReleased(object sender, HandPointerEventArgs e)
    {
      MouseController.SendClick();
    }
}
   }
```

The mouse controller:

```
   public class MouseController
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags, UInt32 dx, UInt32 dy, UInt32 dwData, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    private const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

    internal static void SendClick()
    {
        SendDown();
        SendUp();
    }

    internal static void SendUp()
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, new System.IntPtr());
    }
    internal static void SendDown()
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, new System.IntPtr());
    }

    internal static void MoveMouse(Point p)
    {
        SetCursorPos((int)p.X, (int)p.Y);
    }
}
```

I have to simulate a mouse click with the grip gesture in order to navigate the web app, but I can't make the click pass throught the form. 
The project is a little collage of some Kinect function I found on the net, but now I'm stuck here and Google has not been so usefull.. 
Please help, i'm still a rookie..

Comment: Not sure if this helps you, but see an example how I generated "right click mouse event": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693246/click-event-to-right-click-event-data-binding-template

Comment: The click event is probably getting swallowed up by the full screen application you have - Why don't you change it so you have a small transparent, borderless window with a hand or something on it, and move it around based on input from the kinect, and then have the click event trigger to the top left (or wherever) of the window?

Comment: @Joe 
I need the Grip gesture as trigger for the click event but I didn't find a real way to make but I have not found any way except through the algorithm of microsoft (which involves the use of the ScrollViewer ) to be able to read that gesture. Besides, my boss has rejected the direct use of the position of the cursor through the joint of the hand because the result was very little fluid and usable. 
So now I'm a little stuck..

Comment: @Nikteddy I haven't tried this, if I have chance I'll give it a shot tomorrow. Have you tried responding to the event by: Minimising the window, executing the "Click" action, and then restoring the window state?